# Finding the big theta bound

Tags: bounds, big-o

Give big theta bound for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i * i < n) {
         for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
             count++;
         }
    }
    else {
        int k = i;
        while (k > 0) {
            count++;
            k = k / 2;
        }
    }
}
```

So here's what I think..Not sure if it's right though:

The first for loop will run for n iterations. Then the for for loop within the first for loop will run for n iterations as well, giving O(n^2).

For the else statement, the while loop will run for n iterations and the k = k/ 2 will run for logn time giving O(nlogn). So then the entire thing will look like n^2 + nlogn and by taking the bigger run time, the answer would be theta n^2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the result is `O(nlogn)` because `i*i` is typically not smaller than n for a linear n. The else branch will dominate.

Example:

```
n= 10000
after i=100 the else part will be calculated instead of the inner for loop
```